# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am unable to fetch the data abjects in the json file please let give suggestion to run this code. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {current_page, data, first_page_url, from, last_page, last_page_url, next_page_url, path, per_page, prev_page_url, to, total}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import axios from './axios';
   import './App.css';


   function App() {
     const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
         const fetchUrl = {};

         async function fetchData(){
          const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
          setTransactions(request?.data?.payload);
    
          return request;
        }
        fetchData();
   }, []);

  console.log(transactions);


  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
    <h2>Transactions</h2>
    <p>Current Page {transactions?.current_page}</p>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>datetime</th>
     </tr>
     if ({transactions}) {
      transactions?.data?.map(transaction => (
        <tr>
          <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}</td>
          <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.CardOnHand}</td>
          <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.CardSystem}</td>
        </tr>
       ) )
      }        
    </table>
    </div>
   );
  }

  export default App;
```

JSON Data

```
        {
"success": "true",
"payload": {
    "current_page": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481619",
            "TransQuantity": "37.729999999999997",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "2246.4399",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:49:41.547",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32351578.0000",
            "Mileage": "138012",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "843",
            "vehicle_desc": "TATA",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9240",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:49:41.550",
            "ID_CARDS": "1757",
            "Number": "6247",
            "PAN": "9100339200027624722",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "31"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481618",
            "TransQuantity": "187.80999800000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "11182.2100",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:49:41.507",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32351390.0000",
            "Mileage": "163216",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1150",
            "vehicle_desc": "SEMI SLEEPER BUS(HPV)",
            "LicensePlate": "MP13P7281",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:49:41.517",
            "ID_CARDS": "1325",
            "Number": "6993",
            "PAN": "9100339200027699328",
            "Cardholder": "TRA MP09FA6372 TO MP13P7281",
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "32"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481617",
            "TransQuantity": "2731.3500979999999",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "65.8600",
            "TransAmount": "179886.7031",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:48:50.547",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32348658.0000",
            "Mileage": null,
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": null,
            "vehicle_desc": null,
            "LicensePlate": null,
            "ActMilageType": null,
            "ActMilageDate": null,
            "ID_CARDS": "1997",
            "Number": "2275",
            "PAN": "000000000011227564=",
            "Cardholder": "sand to indore",
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "13",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE-8587",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "33"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481616",
            "TransQuantity": "210.270004",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "12519.4805",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:34:44.900",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32348448.0000",
            "Mileage": "346718",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "771",
            "vehicle_desc": "LP0 1515",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9071",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:34:44.903",
            "ID_CARDS": "1569",
            "Number": "6325",
            "PAN": "9100339200027632527",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "34"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481615",
            "TransQuantity": "75.300003000000004",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "4483.3599",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:26:17.830",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32348372.0000",
            "Mileage": "391441",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1026",
            "vehicle_desc": "VOLVO",
            "LicensePlate": "MP04PA7245",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 12:42:41.030",
            "ID_CARDS": "1710",
            "Number": "7264",
            "PAN": "9100339200027726428",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "35"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481614",
            "TransQuantity": "208.11000100000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "12390.8701",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:26:17.797",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32348164.0000",
            "Mileage": "2034680",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": null,
            "vehicle_desc": null,
            "LicensePlate": null,
            "ActMilageType": null,
            "ActMilageDate": null,
            "ID_CARDS": "1989",
            "Number": "15",
            "PAN": "000000000011235641=",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "36"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481613",
            "TransQuantity": "31.100000000000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "1851.6899",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:19:05.530",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32348132.0000",
            "Mileage": "222630",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "801",
            "vehicle_desc": "TATA",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9193",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:19:05.537",
            "ID_CARDS": "1590",
            "Number": "6346",
            "PAN": "9100339200027634622",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "37"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481612",
            "TransQuantity": "262.040009",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "15601.8604",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:19:05.500",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32347870.0000",
            "Mileage": "177760",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1142",
            "vehicle_desc": "SEMI SLEEPER BUS(HPV)",
            "LicensePlate": "MP13P5481",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:19:05.507",
            "ID_CARDS": "791",
            "Number": "6750",
            "PAN": "9100339200027675021",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "38"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481611",
            "TransQuantity": "37.959999000000003",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "2260.1399",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:11:25.840",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32347832.0000",
            "Mileage": "2034680",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "763",
            "vehicle_desc": "VALVO",
            "LicensePlate": "MP04PA2763",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:11:25.847",
            "ID_CARDS": "1564",
            "Number": "6320",
            "PAN": "9100339200027632022",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "39"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "481610",
            "TransQuantity": "207.63000500000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "12362.2900",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-16 10:11:25.820",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32347624.0000",
            "Mileage": "384249",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1075",
            "vehicle_desc": "TATA",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9052",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-16 10:11:25.833",
            "ID_CARDS": "1605",
            "Number": "6361",
            "PAN": "9100339200027636122",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000",
            "row_num": "40"
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://csplfms.ddns.net:8081/hecpoll-api/public/api/transactions?page=1",
    "from": 31,
    "last_page": 7380,
    "last_page_url": "http://csplfms.ddns.net:8081/hecpoll-api/public/api/transactions?page=7380",
    "next_page_url": "http://csplfms.ddns.net:8081/hecpoll-api/public/api/transactions?page=5",
    "path": "http://csplfms.ddns.net:8081/hecpoll-api/public/api/transactions",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": "http://csplfms.ddns.net:8081/hecpoll-api/public/api/transactions?page=3",
    "to": 40,
    "total": 73796
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate but the problem is `if ({transactions})`.  You need all Javascript code like `if` to be inside curly braces.  But I think since you are using optional chaining you don't need the `if` at all?  Try `</tr>{transactions?.data?.map(transaction => (...))}</table>`.

Answer (score 2):

When you `map` over an array and return elements you need to set a `key` **on the outermost element**.  So the three `td` lines don't actually need a `key`.  The `tr` around them *does* need a `key` and it doesn't have one.

The "Objects are not valid as a React child" error is due to a syntax error in `if ({transactions}) {`  You need all Javascript code including that `if` to be inside curly braces. But since you are using optional chaining you don't need the `if` at all.

Though not required, there are some improvements that you can make to your `table` HTML syntax.  You can add [`thead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) tags around the head and body.  You can add `scope="col"` to your [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) elements in the header row.  You could use the ID column as the row header with `<th scope="row">` if you want to.

```
return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <h2>Transactions</h2>
    <p>Current Page {transactions?.current_page}</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Id</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">datetime</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {transactions?.data?.map((transaction) => (
          <tr key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>
            <th scope="row">{transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}</th>
            <td>{transaction.CardOnHand}</td>
            <td>{transaction.CardSystem}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to render something, you have to enclose it in {}
2. <strike>You're not returning anything from your map function</strike>
3. Closing tags don't have spaces before /
4. You are checking if transactions exist, but still use optional chaining for no reason. If is not valid in return at all.
5. JSX arrays have to have a key property

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import './App.css';


function App() {
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUrl = {};

        async function fetchData() {
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setTransactions(request?.data?.payload);

            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="wrapper" >
            <h2>Transactions </h2>
            <p> Current Page {transactions?.current_page} </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id </th>
                    <th> Quantity </th>
                    <th> datetime </th>
                </tr>
                {transactions?.data?.map((transaction, index) => (
                    (<tr key={index}>
                        <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS} > {transaction.ID_PAYMENTS} </td>
                        < td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS} > {transaction.CardOnHand} </td>
                        < td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS} > {transaction.CardSystem} </td>
                    </tr>)
                ))}
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think `key` is not required for `<td>` tags but more to `<tr>` tag, and `key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}` should have been put there

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use `if` clause in your return.
2. In `map` function, each component returned should have a unique key.

> ```
> { transactions?.data?.length && transactions.data.map(transaction => <tr>
>       <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}</td>
>       <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.CardOnHand}</td>
>       <td key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>{transaction.CardSystem}</td>
>     </tr>
> }
> ```